# Legend height limit and legend scroll

Tags: vue-chartjs

How to limit legend height and add X-scroll to it.
The legend occupies the entire canvas height and limits the chart height.
I need to add X-scorll for legend, and add search for it, but I'll try to figure out the search myself

I tried to find something suitable in the options prop, but nothing helped